# Highcharts bubble chart dataLabels overlapping despite z-index

Tags: highcharts, label, overlapping, bubble-chart

I have a problem with the bubble chart. In fact, i have some points which have the same coordinates with a different name and maybe a different size (z point). For these points, i have a superposition of labels. The z-index solution doesn't work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843238/highcharts-bubble-chart-datalabels-overlappinghttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843238/highcharts-bubble-chart-datalabels-overlapping).

Does anyone know of any solution to this problem ?

I thought to do a label connector like the pie chart but i do not how to do.

My code :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
                    categories:['R0', 'R1', 'R2','R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
                    bubble: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            useHTML: true,
                            //inside: false,
                            //y:-10,
                            //overflow: false,
                            //crop: false,
                            style: { textShadow: 'none',fontSize: '10px',color:'black' },
                            formatter: function() {
                                return "<i>" + this.point.name.split(' ').join('<br>') + "</i>";
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip : {
                                            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                                            pointFormat : 'S : <i>{point.name}</i><br>Y : {point.y}<br>Num : {point.z}'

                                        }
                    }
                },
        series: [
            {
            name:  'Sample1',
            marker: { fillColor: '#89A54E' },
            data: [
            { name:'A',x:2,y:0.0,z:47},
            { name:'Z',x:3,y:1.0,z:35},
            { name:'E',x:4,y:0.5,z:9},
            { name:'R',x:0,y:1.0,z:34},
            { name:'T',x:3,y:0.0,z:37},
            { name:'T',x:2,y:0.0,z:22},
            { name:'p',x:0,y:1.0,z:39},
            { name:'m',x:2,y:0.5,z:47},
            { name:'h',x:0,y:0.5,z:48},
            { name:'l',x:5,y:1.0,z:25},
            ]
            },
            {
            name:  'Sample2',
            marker: { fillColor: '#92A8CD' },
            data: [
            { name:'AB',x:2,y:0.5,z:23},
            { name:'CA',x:6,y:0.5,z:19},
            { name:'OP',x:3,y:0.5,z:21},
            { name:'CP',x:1,y:0.75,z:38},
            { name:'TS',x:3,y:1.0,z:13},
            { name:'SP',x:0,y:1.0,z:43},
            { name:'SE',x:4,y:1.0,z:2},
            { name:'CS',x:6,y:0.5,z:48},
            { name:'CL',x:1,y:0.5,z:5},
            { name:'H',x:1,y:0.0,z:11},
            ]
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Highcharts can hide overlapping data labels if you set useHTML to false, but if you want to keep all labels then maybe simple moving all labes from one series a little up and from secon - down will solve your problem? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmU8/35/

Comment: I went on a 3d scatter plot because it's most easy to see the data labels by changing the Z-index and the size is set by the radius. But thanks a lot.

Comment: You can always disable overlapping feature, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a `labelrank` property on the Highcharts point objects that can be used to dictate which point labels are on top. It can be used when you're creating your data like this:

```
data: [{
        x: 1, y: 1, labelrank: 1, name: 'A'
        },{
        x: 1, y: 1, labelrank: 2, name: 'B' 
      }]
```

Or it can be updated on an individual point to bring that point's dataLabel to the front by doing something like this: `chart.series[0].points[0].update({labelrank: 3});`

I had a similar issue and created [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579518/highcharts-bubble-chart-how-to-move-an-individual-points-data-label-datalabe/36599536#36599536) question on SO that just was answered.

**EDIT**

They have updated their docs to include `series.data.labelrank` as well: [http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.labelrank](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cbubble%3E.data.labelrank)