# Highcharts bubble chart datalabels not display

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, label, bubble-chart

From [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble) library I have used bubble chart. In that bubble chart, 
datalables for some of the bubble are not getting displayed.

Please have a look below screenshot and also jsfiddle demo

[image: Highcharts bubble chart data labale issue]

```
Jsfiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/twsfrnxz/
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427876/highcharts-is-it-possible-to-show-all-data-labels-in-a-bubble-chart-without-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data label is not displayed because there is not enough space. To display it anyway enable `allowOverlap` property:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            ...,
            allowOverlap: true
        }
    }
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r50fw7Lk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.allowOverlap